access alias from another file c++
I was trying to access the alias from another file so called "cph.h" and use it in the current file "wsManager.h" on visual studio but compiler throws the following error
Error C2653 'json': is not a class or namespace name

cph.h file
#pragma once

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>

#include <json.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include <MT4ManagerAPI.h>
#include "mt4Manager.h"
#include "wsManager.h"

using json = nlohmann::json;

wsManager.h
#pragma once
#include "chp.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;


class wsManager
{
 .....
    void postProcessData(beast::flat_buffer bufferData) {
        // Error here
        json json_buffer_data = json::parse(beast::buffers_to_string(bufferData.data())); <- error at this line

        wsResponseData.instrument = json_buffer_data["instrument_id"].dump();
        for (const auto& obj : json_buffer_data["bids"]) {
            wsResponseData.bids = obj["price"];
        }

        for (const auto& obj : json_buffer_data["asks"]) {
            wsResponseData.asks = obj["price"];
        }
    }
};


Your bug is cph.h includes wsManager.h and wsManager.h includes cph.h You can't have circular include loops. Related but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

@drescherjm Thanks for the answer. Successfully resolved this after i remove the header file. Cheers!

Your cph.h file is longer than it should be for a [mre]. Reducing the main content to using json = nlohmann::json; is a great first step. The next step is to eliminate all the header files except the one that defines nlohmann::json. (And if that eliminates the error, use a process of elimination to determine which other header you need to get the error.) Similarly, you should prune down the aliases and headers for wsManager.h.

As mentioned by @drescherjm, simply remove the header file and prevent the ciruclar include loops does the trick and problem solved.
